# deploying multiple applications to Tomcat not getting log Information in Console?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I am using tomcat7,I have deployed more than 2 applications in single instnce of tomcat and its working fine.
But Logs are not coming in console.But war's working fine how to log information in different log file.

I want to create separate log files based on applications.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link:

[**Logging in Tomcat** (Tomcat 7)](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/logging.html)

It depends on the logging facility the web applications use, but all of today's logging frameworks can be configured where, how and what to log.

First you have to find out what logging framework(s) your webapps use. The linked page contains examples how to configure them to log into files whose names can be given with templates.

Also check out the official (documentation) sites of the logging framework(s) that are in question for more information, details and customization.

Answer (score 0):

First of all ensure that the you have set the expected logging level. To do this open the file conf/logging.properties . You may want to set the your.package.FileHandler.level = FINE
Although you may be overwhelmed by the amount of logging :)

To get two different logs you may try creating two separate handler for your application.

```html
handlers = ... , com.package1.FileHandler, com.package2.FileHandler

...
...
...

com.package1.FileHandler.level = FINE
com.package1.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
com.package1.FileHandler.prefix = app1

com.package2.FileHandler.level = FINE
com.package2.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
com.package2.FileHandler.prefix = app2
```